# UiBarButtonItem background image not showing until first tap

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uibarbuttonitem

In my AppDelegate.m file I have created the following back button style:

```
    UIImage *backBtnImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"back.png"];
    [[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonBackgroundImage: backBtnImage forState: UIControlStateNormal barMetrics: UIBarMetricsDefault];
    [[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonBackgroundImage: backBtnImage forState: UIControlStateHighlighted barMetrics: UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

For some reason the background image only shows on each view after the space where the button is is tapped once - it loads everytime for each view after that.

I've tried cleaning the project but to no avail.

Comment: Are you setting that and adding the button from the main thread?

Comment: The above code in set in AppDelegate's didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method. Have tried adding the code to dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{... block but still no joy. The back button gets added automatically by iOS when I push a view controller.

Comment: Hello, I have exactly the same problem. Did you found out what the issue is?

Comment: Still looking for a solution to this. Any luck?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, if your running this on your simulator, try a reseting content and settings, if that doesnt work, I know the iOS devices have some issues with caching, try changing the photo name.png in both the actual file and the reference in xcode.

Comment: Nope no luck. Problem occurs on both simulator and iOS device.